# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly

Tags: android

I'm trying to read image from gallery. I'm using Motorola G2 device with marshmallow android version.

Method:

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};                   

   // Cursor cursor = this.getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    Cursor cursor = this.getActivity().managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
    System.out.println("In Iconiq:: In postImage:: Index:: " + column_index);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Comment: i would certainly check `cursor` for null, then call `cursor.moveToFirst();` prior to referencing said cursor.

Comment: yeah. but cursor returns null even image is selected from device gallery ?@DavidM